# How can I monitor a folder, and it's subdirectories for changes, and show the diff

Tags: windows, windows-10, filesystems

I need to monitor a folder and it's subdirectory for file modifications.  I need to specifically know what modifications occur.

After thinking about this problem, the files that I want to monitor must have a copy created, to be used for comparison when a modification is detected.

I'd rather not implement this myself, if there is already a good tool that will do this.  The tools I found in my initial search only alert to changes, but do not show the diff before/after.

Comment: Beyond Compare is one the most sophisticated software apps to do this kind of work, but (a) it does not make backups of files with differences and (b) it is not resident, that is, it does not scan real time. I have not seen anything like you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Robocopy` with specific parameters to ***only list*** the files in a source location that are different which would be copied over to a  destination location.

The files you are monitoring which have been modified, use this block of `Robocopy` code wrapped in PowerShell code to create a destination copy beforehand and as needed.

### 1. Copy source to destination

```
$SRC   = "C:\Source\Folder"
$DEST  = "C:\Destination\Folder"
$FName = "*.*"
$OPT   = "/S /R:5 /NS /NC /NDL /FP /NJH /NJS"
$CMD   = "robocopy $SRC $FName $DEST $OPT"
Invoke-Expression $CMD
```

You can then use this block of `Robocopy` code wrapped in PowerShell to ***list the full path of any source location files that have been modified*** not matching those in the destination location.

### 2. List source changed files

```
$SRC   = "C:\Source\Folder"
$DEST  = "C:\Destination\Folder"
$FName = "*.*"
$OPT   = "/S /R:5 /NS /NC /NDL /FP /NJH /NJS /L"
$CMD   = "robocopy $SRC $FName $DEST $OPT"
$v = Invoke-Expression $CMD

$v.Trim() | % { $_ };
```

The output of the second block will **list only those files that have been modified**. This will not recopy the file back over again. Putting this output into a different format or logging is just a trivial matter.

You can rerun the first block any time as needed to actually copy over any modified files to the destination location accordingly based on your workflow.

**Example Output**

```
C:\Src\MP\List.txt
C:\Src\MP\Archive\Dance\Cool.mp3
C:\Src\MP\Archive\Dance\Too Cool.mp3
C:\Src\MP\Archive\Dance\Way Too Cool.mp3
C:\Src\MP\Archive\Dance\Silly So Cool.mp3
C:\Src\MP\Archive\Dance\Too Fool For School.mp3
C:\Src\MP\Archive\Dance\Nerd School Cool.mp3
C:\Src\MP\Dance\Cool.mp3
C:\Src\MP\Dance\Too Cool.mp3
C:\Src\MP\Dance\Way Too Cool.mp3
C:\Src\MP\Dance\Silly So Cool.mp3
```

### A different variation

Here is a different variation of this logic using PowerShell that will run `Robocopy` to only list modified files. It will evaluate the result of the `Robocopy` command that is invoked, and only list the files it finds which have changed.

```
$SRC   = "C:\Source\Folder"
$DEST  = "C:\Destination\Folder"
$FName = "*.*"
$OPT   = "/S /R:5 /NS /NC /NDL /FP /NJH /NJS /L"
$CMD   = "robocopy $SRC $FName $DEST $OPT"
$v = Invoke-Expression $CMD;

If ($v) {
    Write-Host "*** Modified files listed below ***" -ForegroundColor Magenta;
    $v.Trim() | % { 
        Write-Host $_ -ForegroundColor Yellow;};
    };
```

---

## Support Resources

- - [Robocopy](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html)
  - `Robocopy /?`

    > ```
    > /S :: copy Subdirectories, but not empty ones.
    > /L :: List only - don't copy, timestamp or delete any files.
    > /FP :: include Full Pathname of files in the output.
    > /NS :: No Size - don't log file sizes.
    > /NC :: No Class - don't log file classes.
    > /NDL :: No Directory List - don't log directory names.
    > /NJH :: No Job Header.
    > /NJS :: No Job Summary.
    > ```
  - [Invoke-Expression](https://ss64.com/ps/invoke-expression.html)
  - [ForEach-Object](https://ss64.com/ps/foreach-object.html)

    > Standard [Aliases](https://ss64.com/ps/get-alias.html) for Foreach-Object: the '`%`' symbol, ForEach
  - [Trim()](https://ss64.com/ps/trim.html)

    > By default `trim()` will remove leading and trailing spaces and leading and trailing line breaks.