# Batch to copy file with subsequent file names

Tags: batch, copy, numbering, overwrite

I currently have robocopy monitoring files in a folder for changes.  When any files changes, robocopy does it job by making a copy.  The problem is, I see no way to have multiple copies of the same file, as robocopy overwrites.  The result should be no different than if you right-click>copy then right-click>paste in the same folder:

```
data.txt 
data - copy.txt 
data - copy(2).txt 
data - copy(3).txt 
.... - copy(n).txt
```

So I either need a robocopy command (though I didn't see any) to copy and rename subsequent files, or something like robocopy that can monitor and copy without overwriting but do some sort of subsequent naming convention.

My 30 hours of searching for an answer never comes up with what I need or I don't know how to search for it properly.

Comment: If you could have the Robocopy destination folder be datetime stamped like `FolderName_20220617_0900AM` of just the files that are different since the last backup, you could have robocopy just log it, and then read the log file with PowerShell and parse the NEW lines and get the full paths of the NEW file, and then just copy those from the original destination to the date and time appended folder. SO technically you would monitor a source folder and different working folder and then copy just the changed files that period to the date time archived area. I think it could work. Ideas only!!

Comment: Actually I wrote this answer that should help with that sort of idea to get you started maybe if that sounds like it'd suffice. https://superuser.com/questions/1720375/how-can-i-monitor-a-folder-and-its-subdirectories-for-changes-and-show-the-di/1720393#1720393

Answer (score 0):

```bat
@echo off && setlocal

set "_files=LostIsland.ark,1153356741.arktribe,LocalPlayer.arkprofile"
set "_dirBk=D:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\ARK\ShooterGame\Saved\LostIslandSavedArksLocal"

%:^)
for %%i in (%_files%)do 2>nul (
     fc "%_dirBk%\%%~nxi" "%_dirBk%\Backup Files\%%~nxi" /b | findstr /b "FC:.no.*" >nul || (
         call %:^O "%%~nxi" "%_dirBk%\Backup Files" 
        )
    )
    
timeout /t 60 /nobreak >nul & goto %:^)

%:^O
if "%~nx1" == "" (endlocal && exit /b)else pushd "%~2"
for /l %%L in (1,1,99)do if not exist .\"%~n1(%%~L)%~x1" (
     copy ..\"%~nx1" . && copy ..\"%~1" ".\%~n1(%%~L)%~x1"
     popd & exit /b
    )
```