# Copy file from folder to another folder every 5 min if file has changed. No sync

Tags: backup

I have a excel sheet where a person fills in data.
This occurs offline on a laptop.

Excel sheet has auto save.

But to be sure to have a backup if the person delete some rows by mistake, I would like to copy file every 5 minute to another folder on the laptop.

But without deleting the file already copied to the other folder.
I know this will give me a lot of excel files in that other folder.
But it's only 100 files x max 200 kB a day and then they will be deleted

I have asked in another forum if robocopy could do that.
But seems not.

I got a link to a case in this forum here. But not sure I understand fully to transfer this to me.
I'm not especially good in scripts :-)

[Batch to copy file with subsequent file names](https://superuser.com/questions/1726910/batch-to-copy-file-with-subsequent-file-names)

Last comment: The file is in a local google drive folder..
But if that's not possible I could move it to a normal windows folder on C drive.

Comment: Why not simply use google sheets? This includes versioning, so any edit can be undone.

Comment: If the file is stored on Microsoft OneDrive, OneDrive will also do versioning similarly to google sheets. If you really need software, Free File Sync can be configured using Real Time Sync to do exactly what you want. Make a backup of files every time it changes, with a time-out timer to ensure its not backupping too often. It can also move older versions to another folder with versioning numbers and delete them after x days.

Comment: Hi.. thanksYes why not use google sheet. Did not know it had that feature...will look at it.. Thanks

Comment: There's a 'last edit was x' shortcut in the menu bar, right of 'help'. I'll turn it into an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're already using google drive to share these files, so why instead not use [google sheets](https://sheets.google.com/)? This includes versioning, so any edit can be browsed and undone.

If you click the **'Last edit was ...'** link to the right of the *'help'* in the menu, you will get a list of edits/versions and which user made them:

[image]

**Offline use** [is possible](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2375012?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop), assuming you have the Google Drive client installed:

1. On your computer, go to drive.google.com.
2. Right click the Google Docs, Sheets, or Slides file you want to save offline.
3. Turn on "Available offline."

You may have to make sure only one offline version is edited at a time, or there might be colliding versions. This is no different from sending the same xlsx file to multiple authors and receiving edited versions from each of them.

Comment: If you click that 'last edit' link, you'll get a long list of versions. There's a limit of 100 versions in 30 days, after which the oldest ones that aren't marked 'keep' are purged. Note that you should use comments for this, the 'answer' section is for *answers* alone (I've put my response here in case yours gets deleted). I'm not familiar with the [script](https://gist.github.com/abhijeetchopra/99a11fb6016a70287112) you mentioned, but it looks like it makes a more permanent series of snapshots, yes.

Comment: sorry yes... not use to this type of forum and comment / answer. But seems that "last edit" solve my issue if I'm online. Will test it offline.

Comment: Off course it's a online feature "last edit" is gone when off the internet. using downloaded google drive on laptop. So assume I can't use it without person being online?

Comment: I assume that 'last edit' only gets updated from an offline version when Google Drive synchronises it. This I'm not sure about, google sheets I only edit online.